# Dummit and Foote Page :$544$ Proposition $30$

Tags: field-theory

I have a little bit confusion in   Dummit and Foote Book on the Page No $:544$

Proposition $30$: For any field  $F$ there exist  an algebraically closed field $K$ containing $F$

Proof :[image]

**My confusion** : It is given that $$ g_(x_1,x_2,..,x_n,x_{n+1}....,x_m)f_1(x_1) +.......+g_n(x_1,x_2,..,x_n,x_{n+1}...,x_m)f_n(x_n)=1$$

Now if  $x_{n+1}=....=x_m=0$  then $$ g_(x_1,x_2,..,x_n,0....,0)f_1(a_1) +.......+g_n(x_1,x_2,..,0,0...,0)f_n(a_n)=0$$

Here im not getting  that   why $ g_n(x_1,x_2,..,x_n,0....,0)=0?$

Comment: It is the $f_k(\alpha_k)$ the ones that are zero, for $k=1,2,...,n$.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Im sorry for that @Shaun Actually ,it is very Long Proof.So i decided to make screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is not claiming that $g_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n,0,\ldots,0)=0$.

Its point is that $f_i(x_i)$ is $0$, because the $x_i=\alpha_i$s were chosen to make this true.

So no matter what the value of $g_i(\cdots)$ is, it will be killed when you multiply it by $f_i(x_i)$.

Comment: thanks you   @Troposphere  for saving my time .Actually I misunderstood and I  have wasted more than $1$ hours thinking about  why $g_n(x_1,...x_n,0.,0..)=0?$